# What is the correct definition of the correlation of two random variables?

Tags: probability, correlation, random-variable, definition

In the book Signal Processing for Communications by Prandoni and Vetterli, correlation of two variables is defined as the expected value of their product, while the covariance is refered to as the "centralized" correlation (p. 218).

However, when I search online, every definition of correlation (coefficient) of two random variables defines it as the covariance of the two random variables divided by the product of their standard deviations.

What is going on here? Are the two definitions the same or we are talking about two different kinds of correlation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since neither of the characterizations in the first paragraph correspond to the standard senses of the terms "correlation" and "covariance," would you mind quoting this text *verbatim*?  You can find many answers here: [see this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=correlation+definition).

Comment: yes, I've noticed from being on dsp.stackexchange that the correlation in dsp is what is termed the covariance in statistics. Then, they call what we refer to as correlation  as the normalized correlation. It's defined this way in the majority of DSP textbooks and I have no idea why. This causes difficulties, IMHO, because they also tend not subtract off the means in their definitions.